# Dialogue System

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, dialog

I have written an Code, for an Dialoge System, including that the letter appear one by one, but these appear to fast!

How can I slow down this, so the letters need longer to show?

```cs
public class DialogueManager : MonoBehaviour
{

    private Queue<string> sentences;
    public Text nameText;
    public Text dialogueText;
    public Animator animator;

    void Start()
    {
        sentences = new Queue<string>();

    }
    public void StartDialogue(Dialogue dialogue)
    {

        animator.SetBool("isOpen", true);

        nameText.text = dialogue.name;
        
        sentences.Clear();
        foreach (string sentence in dialogue.sentences)
        {
            sentences.Enqueue(sentence);
        };
        DisplayNextSentence();
    }
    public void DisplayNextSentence()
    {
        if (sentences.Count == 0)
        {
            EndDialogue();
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            string sentence = sentences.Dequeue();

            dialogueText.text = sentence;
            StopAllCoroutines();
            StartCoroutine(TypeSentence(sentence));
        }
    }

    IEnumerator TypeSentence (string sentence)
    {
        dialogueText.text = "";
        foreach ( char letter  in sentence.ToCharArray())
        {
            dialogueText.text += letter;
            yield return null;
        }
    }

    void EndDialogue()
    {
        animator.SetBool("isOpen", false);
    }
}
```

```cs
[System.Serializable]
public class Dialogue
{
    public string name;

    [TextArea(3,10)]
    public string[] sentences;
    
}
```

```cs
public class DialogueTrigger : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Dialogue dialogue;

    public void TriggerDialogue()
    {
        FindObjectOfType<DialogueManager>().StartDialogue(dialogue);
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: wait for more than the next frame (which you do here  yield return null; but you knew that as you wrote it right?)

Comment: turn `yield return null` into `yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.1f);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem:**
returning null causes loop to delay one runtime frame
`yield return null;`

**Solution:**

define a variable before loop

`var typingDelay = new WaitForSecondsRealtime(0.05f);` 
(this [*WaitForSecondsRealtime*](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WaitForSecondsRealtime.html) class will insure that next line will run if frame delay between current and future is greater than or equal to float in seconds in this case 0.05 seconds)

and return created variable instead
 `yield return typingDelay;`

**Some references**
[WaitForSecondsRealtime](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WaitForSecondsRealtime.html)
also check
[WaitForSeconds](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WaitForSeconds.html) if you want unity's [Time.timeScale](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-timeScale.html) to affect which may helpful for *pause* or *slow motions*.